# Java MySQL - How do I get info from each row and column

Tags: java, mysql

I am making an online game. I'm using a MySQL database. I'm trying to go through each row and pick out the port the client needs to connect to, so I can connect the client to the servers I gathered through the rows. Here is my code :

```
public class Main {

private static Connection con;
static ResultSet rs;

static String getServers = "SELECT * FROM servers";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    connect();
    Window window = new Window("BLAZE", 800, 600, false);
    while(!window.isCloseRequested()) {
        update();
        render();
        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }
}

private static void connect() {
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql2.freesqldatabase.com/sql233105", "sql233105", "eD7*wA7!");

        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(getServers);
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        //Loop through each row and get info
        // Psuodo code
        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER OF ROWS; i++) {
           int port = ROW.getColumn().getValue();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void update() {

}

private static void render() {

}

}
```

Comment: What's the wrong with your code ?

Comment: wait, you didn't insert your login and password in the connection, right???

Answer (score 0):

Use `rs.next()` to iterate the `ResultSet` and using `rs.getInt()` you can obtain the column value for the rows.

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    int port = rs.getInt("PORT");
    // do process...
}
```